# Modern ASP.NET eCommerce solution

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, e-commerce

i'm done quite lot searching, but just to be sure, is there any modern ASP.NET eCommerce solution? Almoust all solutions i've found are ASP.NET 2.0 based, use no ORM, have no clear separation of layers. And i've searched mostly for commercial packages, hoping that commercial products will offer more, that open source ones? I mean they offer more, but only in features, not in architecture, cutting edge technologies and etc.
Does anybody know any full featured eCommerce solution, that it's build using modern ORM, let's say NHibernate? Linq2Sql? Witch uses ASP.NET MVC? Witch is N-Tier?
If you know such product, please point me to it, may be i'm missing it.
The only project, that is realy modern was sutekishop, but it's quite limited on feature side.

Answer (score 1):

Rob Connery had done a tutorial series based on MVC:
http://blog.wekeroad.com/mvc-storefront/mvc-storefront-part-1/

I've also done an N-Tier ADO.NET (non-ORM) version if you need help in that direction.

Comment: those are nice series, I've followed them, thing is that this time we don't have time to write solution from scratch. And this is I think one of the first times, when we decided to buy complete solution, not write own (not counting components, those we bought before), although it won't be typical b2c eCommerce, that's why we care about what's happening under html.

Comment: Take a look at nopCommerce (free), it has an amazing list of features: http://www.nopcommerce.com/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This service might be a fit, looking at the features it seems to be close to what you are describing:

http://www.aiveacommerceserver.com/Features/Microsoft_SOA_Architecture.htm

Comment: aivea is nice, i've talked to their sales person before, but price tag is too high this time. I think starting price was ~50.000$ and i'm not saying, that they are not worth it, just my project is too small for such price.

Answer (score 0):

I have a webshop in development for 2 years now. It is based on Strongly typed Datasets, and Web Services for interoperability with any engines/platforms for the database. The shop engine is using Linq to Dataset for operations, and I'm using JQuery+Web Services for Ajax on the GUI. The administration pages are written with Linq2SQL. 
If you're interested, please drop an email to balint@cardos.hu

Answer (score 0):

I've gone with SutekiShop project and so far I'm very happy with it. It has clear architecture, although I didn't liked how some of the things were done, I've simply made it my way. If you need something really custom, take a look at SutekiShop.

Answer (score 0):

There was also the old Commerce Starter Kit (ASP.NET), also by Rob Conery and using SubSonic  that eventually turned into dashCommerce (both open source). I've used CSK a few years back, and found quite extendable and adaptable for my needs.